# How to inject service to class with parameters in constructor using autofac?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, autofac

I am developing WPF application and I'm using autofac for dependency injection.
It's not a problem to inject some service to view model with parameterless constructor:

```
public class RoomViewModel
{
    private ISomeService _someService;
    public (ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to inject service to view model with parameters. For example:

```
public class BedViewModel
{
    public BedViewModel(double width, double height)
    {
        //Some logic
    }
}
```

I am creating BedViewModel dynamically in runtime, like this:

```
BedViewModel model = new BedViewModel(width, height);
```

So the question, how to inject service to BedViewModel?

Comment: Honestly I would keep doing what you are doing. Is there a particular reason you want to change from your current approach?

Comment: did you try docs? http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html

Comment: Docs explain how to add hardcoded parameter, but I need to set parameters in runtime.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current approach of doing new BedViewModel(width, height)? How are you suppose to be able to inject a view model that accepts two double values with a service?

Comment: Simple. You are not supposed to use dependency injection with View Models. In this case setting the constructor parameters inline will do. Dependency injection is for composing applications at startup, not for passing data at runtime. See [this post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your constructor parameters via the resolve method:

```
var reader = scope.Resolve<ConfigReader>(new NamedParameter("configSectionName", "sectionName"));
```

In your example it would be:

```
var widthParam = new NamedParameter("width", width);
var heightParam = new NamedParameter("height", height);
var bedViewModel = scope.Resolve<BedViewModel>(widthParam, heightParam);
```

So, if you have a constructor like the following:

```
BedViewModel(IMyService myService, double width, double height)
```

your service will be injected and width/height can be passed via resolve.

[See here for documentation.](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the discussion, wheter you should use Dependency Injection for your View Models, IMHO this is the perfect place where you could use [delegate factory](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html).

First of all you need to create a delegate to tell Autofac how you would like to build your `BedViewModel`:

```
public delegate BedViewModel BedViewModelFactory(double width, double height);
```

Then, you need to inject this factory into the class where you want to create `BedViewModel` instances and use it to create your view models:

```
public SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(BedViewModelFactory bedViewModelFactory)
    {
        var bedViewModel = bedViewModelFactory(1.0, 2.0);
    }
}
```

You pass only width and height parameters, all other parameters would be resolved for you by the container.

If your custom parameters would be different types, you could use `Func` delegate, but it this case it would not work.